# Cant call Javascript function from button onclick event ASP.NET 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net

when ever i call a JavaScript function from `asp:button` `onclick` event i got this error message

**HTML**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFromCalOpen" runat="server" Text=" &gt; "  onclick="ShowCal()"  CssClass = "SElementHide" />
```

Javascript

```
function ShowCal() {

    var elem = document.getElementById('MainContent_CalendarFrom');
    if (elem.visibility = "hidden" )
    {
    elema.style.visibility = "visible";
    elema.style.display = "block";
    }
    else
    {
    elema.style.visibility = "hidden";
    elema.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Error
Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'ShowCal' is not a member of 'ASP.default_aspx'.

Please Help

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Use `OnClientClick` to have your ASP.NET button run a JavaScript method before calling its server-side method. `OnClick` specifies the server side method to run.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnFromCalOpen" runat="server" 
         Text=" &gt; "  CssClass = "SElementHide" 
         OnClientClick="ShowCal()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `OnClientClick` property?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick.aspx

Also, this does not look correct:

```
if (elem.visibility = "hidden")
```

Should be closer to:

```
if (elem.style.visibility == "hidden")
```

Are you also looking for the button to prevent post back?  Then, return false in your ShowCal javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

use `OnClientClick`. `onclick` is for a server side handler.

also you need to check `elem.style.visibility`.

also you're creating `elem` in your js function and then trying to access `elema`.