# How to combine a javascript onclick event with a .net button onClick event?

Tags: .net, button, google-analytics

I have a .net button which has an onClick event, defined in my C# codebehind to do some work (it sets variables and generates a PDF using itextsharp).

I want to implement a google analytics.js tracking event to this same button. How do I have a button that first fires off the javascript, and then the .net onClick?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477647/cant-call-javascript-function-from-button-onclick-event-asp-net-4?

Comment: Ok so that does provide a little more insight. Now I have <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Create Printable PDF" OnClientClick="TrackPDFGeneration()" OnClick="Button3_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False" /> and in my script I have:
 function TrackPDFGeneration(){
            ga('send', 'event', {
                eventCategory: 'ReferralGenerated',
                eventAction: 'click',
                eventLabel: 'Create Referral PDF',
                transport: 'beacon'
            });
        }

Am I doing this correctly? The event is not showing up in my Google Analytics.

Comment: Oh... that worked. It just took a moment to show up. Thank you!